# How do I pass a variable to a component in sveltekit that will be a bound value?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I have an input that I want to make into a component in sveltekit.
The input has a bound value that comes from the parent component page.
Here is a simple example that does not work.
What am I doing wrong?  Thanks in advance!

**Parent Component:**

```
<script>
    import Input from '$lib/components/Input.svelte';

    let hundreds = '';
    let fifties = '';
</script>

<Input inputId="bills-100" boundValue={hundreds} label="$100" />
<Input inputId="bills-50" boundValue={fifties} label="$50" />

<h1>Total:</h1>
{fifties * 50 + hundreds * 100}
```

**Input Component**

```
<script>
    export let inputId;
    export let bindValue;
    export let label;
</script>

<label for={inputId}>{label}</label>
<input
  bind:value={hundreds}
  type="text"
  id={inputId}
/>
```

I do not get any errors but the values are not bound properly and do not display or update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `bind:` on the `Input` component property as well, otherwise the value will not propagate back. Also, you have spelled the property wrong (`bindValue` vs `boundValue`), would just call it `value`:

```html
<Input bind:value={hundreds} ...>
```

The input inside the component itself also references the wrong variable (`hundreds`).